# Using pointers or references to struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, function-parameter

Me and my friend is using structs in our code (our code is separate from each other). Lets take the following example:

```
struct Book {
     char title;
     int pages;
}

void setBook(struct Book *tempBook) {
     tempBook->title = "NiceTitle";
     tempBook->pages = 50;
}
```

The above code is pretty straight forward. The thing is, is there any difference in having these two mains:

```
 int main() {
     struct book obj1;
     setBook(&obj);
    }
```

Or

```
int main() {
    struct Book *obj2;
    setBook(obj2);
}
```

EDIT: 
I was not clear in my statement. I have initialized the pinter to

```
struct Book *obj2 = malloc(sizeof(struct obj2));
```

Comment: In the first snippet : `char title;` -> `char *title;`

Comment: Yes there is a difference. One will work, and one will not work.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik one might work*

Comment: Are you really compiling c++? I strongly suspect you don't

Comment: `struct Book *obj2 = malloc(sizeof(struct obj2));` won't compile, please show the actual code.

Comment: Note: there is a `;` missing after the first `}` .

Comment: Are you kidding me, im aksing for the difference, this is an example.

Comment: There are no references in C!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case of

```
 struct book obj1;
 setBook(&obj);
```

you're passing a valid address<sup>#1</sup> to the function, so the behaviour is defined.

On the other hand,

```
struct Book *obj2;
setBook(obj2);
```

you're passing an unitialized pointer<sup>#2</sup>, accessing which invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

That said, the member `char title;` should be `char *title;`, as the *string literal*, when used as initializer, decays to the pointer to the first element, so you'll need a pointer on the LHS.

---

#1 -- `obj1` is an automatic local variable, and address of that variable is a valid address in the scope.

#2 --  `struct Book *obj2;` defines a pointer and again, `obj2` being an automatic local variable, it is not implicitly initialized to anything. So, the initial value (i.e., the memory address at which the pointer points) is indeterminate and pretty well *invalid*.

Comment: Lets say i did initialize the pointer to an address, whjat would the difference be then?

Comment: @EmilMøllerRinggaard what is `an address`? is it _valid_? How do you know?

Comment: It's on a microprocessor and it compiles, so i think it works

Comment: in general, as long as you pass a valid pointer, id does not matter whether it is the address of a scalar or a pointer variable itself.

Comment: Okay, would you recommend not using a pointer to the struct, and just pass in the &structobject ?

Comment: @EmilMøllerRinggaard That depends, both are valid. The rule of thumb is, if you can avoid using dynamic memory allocation `malloc()` and family, avoid them. Use them only when necessary.

Comment: One last question - Have it even more valid, to avoid dynamic memory allocation on a microcontroller then on a desktop for instance?

Comment: @EmilMøllerRinggaard I'd say, yes.

Comment: @EmilMøllerRinggaard: "It's on a microprocessor and it compiles, so i think it works" - If things were **that** simple! The nasty thing which makes this a very wrong assumption is called "Halting Problem". Simply put: Even if your code compiles without warnings - let alone errors - does not guarantee anything about its correctness.

Answer (score 4):

```
struct Book *obj2;
```

in `main` is just a pointer with an indeterminate value. It doesn't point to anything you allocated. You can dereference it, but that's undefined behavior.

```
struct Book obj1;
```

allocates a `struct Book`. You can use its address and modify its members.

---

Notes:

- `title` from `struct Book` is a `char`, which can only hold one character, not a string (i.e., a pointer). Use `char *` or `const char *` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case you are passing a variable of type 'struct Book'  to 'setBook function. Since you declared the variable hence total memory occupied by obj1 -s sizeof(setBook) i.e. sizeof(char)+sizeof(int) which is equal to 5 bytes. hence you can access as 
obj1 .title(1 byte) and obj1.pages(4 bytes).

NOTE:- Assuming int is 4 byte long.

Let's see what happen in second scenario.

struct Book *obj2;
obj2 size id 4 bytes since it is a general pointer.The field is not divided either and hence we cannot access the field.

Hence,
In second scenario, you need to allocate is dynamically before trying to use the members.The allocation will result in proper sized and properly divided field.